# Column name shown twice in same column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `dataframe` on which I did a `groupby` and `value_counts`:

```
df4.groupby(['City'])['User Type'].value_counts()
```

This gives me following output:

```
City  User Type 
C     Subscriber    238889
      Customer       61110
      Dependent          1
N     Subscriber    269149
      Customer       30159
W     Subscriber    220786
      Customer       79214
```

Now I did `df6=df5.unstack(level=1).reset_index()`

this returned a df like shown below:

[image]

Now i did `df6.set_index('City',inplace=True)`

This produces output:

[image]

I am unable to understand why city is shown under "User Type" and is there a way to remove "User Type" index name

After doing:

```
df6=df5.unstack(level=1).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

and then doing : `df6.set_index('City',inplace=True)`

it still shows city on different level:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `del df6.columns.name`, basically you need to remove the name of the columns index which happens to get the User Type name when you do unstacking.

Comment: I did this but still city is shown on a different level

Comment: You could do del df6.index.name